# what is this plant in my Los Angeles backyard?

Tags: identification

What is this plant? context: Los Angeles backyard

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Comment: I am not familiar with native west-coast flora, but it looks like some sort of ash (*Fraxinus*).

Comment: California Ash?: https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/fraxinus-dipetala https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/fraxinus-uhdei  https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/fraxinus-uhdei-majestic-beauty https://www.leaf-id.com/compound-leaves?page=2

Answer (score 1):

It is the [Common Ash (Fraxinus Excelsior)](http://www.tree-guide.com/ash).

Comment: Unlikely to be F. excelsior, as that species is found only in New England and in the mountains to Ohio and Kentucky. Given its native location, it would most likely need much more rain (and a cold-warm growing season) than is available in LA.

Comment: alright, we'll I'm not sure what it is. It sure looks like the common ash.

Comment: Also, it is watered regularly by my sprinklers, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I was thinking that the reddish-purplish new growth could be a good indicator. If we could see the buds we'd know for sure, but it's the wrong time of year for that. Additionally, F. excelsior is hardy only to zone 7, and LA is in zone 9-ish.